# open tcp port 80 or any specific port on win7 local machine

Tags: windows-7

I want to open the tcp port 80 on win7 professional.I had added inbound rules for tcp port 80 and then i try to telnet 127.0.0.1 80 it prompt can't connect.

It has no service runnning on port 80. just for testing .

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If no service is listening on the port you are trying to connect the connection will never work.

Answer (score 1):

A port is opened by a process. period. it will always be closed if there isn't software listening on that port. Firewalls and NAT and technologies upstream may prevent a user at given location from accessing that port, but the port itself must have been created and bound by a process. allowing the port in a firewall just makes it accessible from additional locations, but doesn't directly affect whether the underlying port is "Open".

for a port to be open from any perspective, there must be a process listening on that port, the port must be on an interface that is accessible (eg not 127.0.0.1), and there must be a path to that interface.

Answer (score 1):

With the telnet, you are trying to connect to the service that is listening to port 80. If there is no such service, then telnet cannot connect to it. So  that is exactly as expected.

It is unclear what you would do to "open  port 80". If you mean that the windows firewall is no longer instructed to filter-out traffic to port 80, then that still does not provide a target that you can telnet to.

Think of the analogy of opening the garden gate. If there is no house in the garden, you still cannot knock at the front door.